# Is it possible to access forecast results in calculated measure?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to find time series outlier using Tableau forecast. I need to compare the actual value with the 95% confidence level in forecast results to determine if it is an outlier.

I understand I can view the forecast results on the chart. But I want to use the forecast results in calculated measure. Is there any way to do it? I cannot find any Tableau functions to retrieve the forecast results.

Answer (score 0):

Xuefei. Doesn't look like there is a way currently, at least going by their help page - https://help.tableau.com/v2019.1/pro/desktop/en-us/forecast_options.htm. If you haven't already considered this - integration with R is easy and that way you could just model it in R (accounting for additive/multiplicative, trend/cyclicity/seasonality) and access the forecast values from R. Integration with Python is also supposed to be easy, although I haven't tried it myself.

Example of code in Tableau to incorporate R code for linear regression (this is the formula for the calc field in Tableau)

```
SCRIPT_REAL("
fv=log(.arg1)
fpri=.arg2
fit=lm(fv~fpri)
exp(fit$fitted)",SUM([Impressions]),SUM([CPM]))
```